# Hadith regarding Umar (ra) threatning to beat sahaba?

Tags: hadith, reference-request

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

Plese help me find a hadith where Umar Ibn Khattab (RA) was approached by some sahabi and he presented a hadith of the Prophet (Saw) to him But Umar (Ra) was skeptical about the information and so he threatens to beat the Sahabi if the hadith is false and when the sahabi presented proof, then umar (Ra) said something along the lines of

> "Oh i wasnt aware of this hadith because i was distracted with the market place"

I've heard and read it a lot of times but not able to find it.

Comment: Its authentic but whats the problem? Umar RA here showed his zeal against lies attributed to the prophet and then when enough evidence was presented he accepted it

Answer (score 5):

There are many narrations of this hadith. I will just link a few:

**Sahih Al-Bukhari:**

- > Narrated 'Ubai bin 'Umar:
  >
  > Abu Musa asked permission to enter upon 'Umar, but seeing that he was
  >   busy, he went away. 'Umar then said, "Didn't I hear the voice of
  >   'Abdullah bin Qais? Allow him to come in." He was called in and 'Umar
  >   said to him, "What made you do what you did." He replied, "We have
  >   been instructed thus by the Prophet" 'Umar said, "Bring proof
  >   (witness) for this, other wise I will do so-and-so to you." Then
  >   'Abdullah bin Qais went to a gathering of the Ansar who then said,
  >   "None but the youngest of us will give the witness for it." So Abu
  >   Sa'id Al-Khudri got up and said, "We used to be instructed thus (by
  >   the Prophet)." 'Umar said, "This tradition of the Prophet () remained
  >   hidden from me. Business in the market kept me busy."
  >
  > <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 7353](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/96/80)</sub>
- <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 6245](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/79/19)</sub>
- <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 2062](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/34/15)</sub>

**Sahih Muslim:**

- > Abu Musa Ash'ari reported that he went to 'Umar b. Khattab and greeted
  >   him by saying:
  >
  > As-Salamu-'Alaikum, here is 'Abdullah b. Qais, but he did not permit
  >   him (to get in). He (Abu Musa Ash'ari) again greeted him with
  >   as-Salamu-'Alaikum and said: Here is Abu Musa, but he (Hadrat 'Umar)
  >   did not permit him (to get in). He again said: As-Salam-u-'Alaikum,
  >   (and said) here is Ash'ari, (then receiving no response he came back).
  >   He (Hadrat 'Umar) said: Bring him back to me, bring him back to me So
  >   he went there (in the presence of Hadrat 'Umar) and he said to him:
  >   Abu Musa, what made you go back, while we were busy in some work? He
  >   said: I heard Allah's Messenger (may. peace be upon him) as saying:
  >   Permission should be sought thrice. And if you are permitted, (then
  >   get in), otherwise go back. He said: Bring witness to this fact,
  >   otherwise I shall do this and that, i. e. I shall punish you. Abu Musa
  >   went away and 'Umar said to him (on his departure): It he (Abu Musa)
  >   finds a witness he should meet him by the side of the pulpit in the
  >   evening and it he does not find a witness you would not find him
  >   there. When it was evening he (Hadrat 'Umar) found him (Abu Musa)
  >   there. He (Hadrat 'Umar) said: Abu Musa, have you been able to find a
  >   witness to what you have said? He said: Yes. Here is Ubayy bin Ka'b,
  >   whereupon he (Hadrat 'Umar) said: Yes, he is an authentic (witness).
  >   He (Hadrat 'Umar) said: Abu Tufail (the kunya of Ubayy b. Ka'b), what
  >   does he (Abu Musa say? Thereupon he said: Ibn Khattab, I heard Allah's
  >   Messenger (ﷺ) as saying so. Do not prove to be a hard (task-master)
  >   for the Companions of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), whereupon he Hadrat 'Umar
  >   said: Hallowed be Allah. I had heard something (in this connection),
  >   but I wished it to be established (as an undeniable fact).
  >
  > <sub>[Sahih Muslim 2154 a](https://sunnah.com/muslim/38/48)</sub>

**Sunan Ibn-Majah:**

- > It was narrated from Abu Saeed Khudri that Abu Musa asked permission
  >   to enter upon 'Umar three times, and he did not give him permission,
  >   so he went away.'Umar sent word to him saying: "Why did you go back?"
  >   He said: "I asked permission to enter three times, as the Messenger of
  >   Allah(ﷺ) enjoined upon us, then if we are given permission we should
  >   enter, otherwise we should go back." He said: "You should bring me
  >   proof of that, or else!" Then he came to a gathering of his people and
  >   asked them to swear by Allah concerning that, and they did so, so he
  >   let him go."
  >
  > <sub>[Sunan Ibn Majah 3706](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/33/50)</sub>

**Sunan Abi Dawud:**

- > Abu Sa’id al-Khudri said: I was sitting in one of the meeting of the
  >   Ansar. Abu Musa came terrified. We asked him; what makes you
  >   terrified? He replied: ‘Umar sent for me; so I went to him and asked
  >   his permission three times, but he did not permit me (to enter), so I
  >   came back. He asked; what has prevented you from coming to me? I
  >   replied: I came and asked permission three times, but it was not
  >   granted to me (so I returned). The Messenger of Allah (May peace be
  >   upon him) has said: When one of you asks permission three times and it
  >   is not granted to him, he should go away. He (‘Umar’) said; establish
  >   the proof of it. So Abu Sa’id said: the youngest of the people will
  >   accompany you. So Abu Sa’id got up with him and testified.
  >
  > <sub>[Sunan Abi Dawud 5180](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/408)</sub>
- http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/409
- https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/410
- http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/411
- http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/412

**Jami'at Tirmidhi:**

- https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/42/3